# command to randomly select something from a table based on a set percent chance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: please view image before reading post]

as seen in the image i have a list of countries, and a list of corresponding percents. i know that you can use commands to randomly select something from a list, but i would like to randomly select something based on its percent. (china is 18.47%, so i would like to select china 18.47% of the time) the percent in my table corresponds to its likelyhood of it be chosen at random. now that i have the list, i would like to be able to randomly chose one based on its percent though. what command can i use to do this. im very new to excel so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make a start by googling how to select a random item from a list, then you need to keep a tally of how many each has been picked. It's not really clear what you are ultimately trying to achieve. Select to what end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve by adding two more columns.

Column A: Number your rows starting with 1.

Column D: Cumulative of C.

```
D2 Formula: =sum(c1:d1)
```

Drag down your formula. Then in your results, here's the formula for G2:

```
=VLOOKUP(MATCH(RAND(),$D$2:$D$6),A:B,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: You can do it without Column A:  `=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(RAND(),D:D))`  Otherwise a good approach.

Comment: Good catch @ScottCraner

Answer (score 0):

Without helper columns:

```
=INDEX($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)),MATCH(RAND(),SUMIF(OFFSET($B$1,0,0,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)-1))),"<>")))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]